Is it okay to pray when naked?
Is the salat accepted when we pray without wearing any clothing and without seen by anyone?
For example praying in the house or a safe and enclosed space naked.

No, unless you do not have any clothes. If you do have the means to cover your 'awrah then it is obligatory and a condition for validity of Salah. If you prayed without covering it then the prayer would be invalid and will need to be repeated.
It does not make any difference whether you are praying individually or in a congregation, neither does being in seclusion or praying in darkness make any difference - see Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah.
The evidence for it includes:



خذوا زينتكم عند كل مسجد
take your adornment at every masjid (place of prostration)
— Quran 7:31

As it is narrated in the exegesis of this verse that it is about wearing clothes during prayer. This verse is a command to wear adornment (i.e. clothing) at every Salah.



لا يقبل الله صلاة حائض إلا بخمار
Salat of a women who has reached the age of menstruation is not accepted without a Khimar
— Tirmizi , Ibn Majah etc.

The evidence from this hadith is obvious.

Because it is part of showing respect towards Allah when facing Him.


